# How to fix MySQL CREATE FUNCTION query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-function

I want to add mysql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `chf_get_translation`(translation_id INT, site_lang INT) 
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

  DECLARE translation TEXT;

  SELECT title 
    INTO translation 
    FROM chf_translations 
   WHERE key_id = translation_id 
     AND lang_id = site_lang;

  RETURN translation;

END
```

But get error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `chf_get_translation`(translation_id INT, site_lang INT) 
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

  DECLARE translation TEXT;

  SELECT title 
    INTO translation 
    FROM chf_translations 
   WHERE key_id = translation_id 
     AND lang_id = site_lang;

  RETURN translation;

END$$
```

Comment: This helps thanks;

But now i get error:
ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: I found answer. I need "READS SQL DATA" after "RETURNS text CHARSET utf8"

Answer (score 2):

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE FUNCTION `chf_get_translation`(translation_id INT, site_lang INT) 
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  DECLARE translation TEXT;

  SELECT title 
    INTO translation 
    FROM chf_translations 
   WHERE key_id = translation_id 
     AND lang_id = site_lang;

  RETURN translation;

END$
```